# search file in all sub directories

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell. I'm using this script to find a file in a specific folder:

```
If (Test-Path -Path C:\files\02.jpg -PathType Leaf) {
    Write-Output "Year - NULL in argument"
    exit 1
}
```

Is it possible to search my file `02.jpg` in all folders and subdirectories of `C:\`

Comment: You mean: `$file = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter '02.jpg' -File -Recurse | Select-Object -First 1; if ($file) { "Found it here: $($file.FullName)" } else { "Not found" }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Get-ChildItem`
Where `-Filter` will be your file you want to find. And make it recursively `-Recurse`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path V:\Myfolder -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

Comment: Although it searches the specified directory, it doesn't return a `false` or `true` value. I want to use `if` and check a condition according to my question. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Pass this command into a variable.  CMD=$(Get-ChildItem -Path V:\Myfolder -Filter CopyForbuild.bat -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force); echo